# Dictionary Key Not Found When It Does Exist

Tags: c#, dictionary, double-precision

Why is my Dictionary saying a key doesn't exist when I just inserted it? Is it to do with my `Equals` method or double comparision?

Here is the code:

```
// Test: I know the dictionary contains nCoord but its saying the key doesn't exist
Dictionary<UTMCoordinate, int> planes = new Dictionary<UTMCoordinate, int>();
UTMCoordinate nCoord    = new UTMCoordinate(337394.136407966, 6263820.40182064, 0, 56, UTMCoordinate.Hemisphere.H_SOUTHERN);
planes[nCoord]          = 1;

bool exists = planes.ContainsKey(nCoord);  // always returns false
```

My implementation of `UTMCoordinate` is below:

```
public class UTMCoordinate
{
    public enum                 Hemisphere {H_NOTHERN, H_SOUTHERN};
    public const double         DIF_TOLERANCE    = 0.0005;
    public double               x               { get; set; }
    public double               y               { get; set; }
    public double               elev            { get; set; }
    public uint                 UTMZone         { get; set; }
    public Hemisphere           hemisphere      { get; set; }

    public UTMCoordinate(double x, double y, double elev=double.MinValue, uint utmZone=uint.MinValue, Hemisphere hemisphere=Hemisphere.H_SOUTHERN) {
        this.x          = x;
        this.y          = y;
        this.elev       = elev;
        this.UTMZone    = utmZone;
        this.hemisphere = hemisphere;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
            hash = hash * 23 + x.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + y.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + elev.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + UTMZone.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + hemisphere.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        UTMCoordinate other = obj as UTMCoordinate;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return double.Equals(x, other.x) && double.Equals(y, other.y) && double.Equals(elev, other.elev) && uint.Equals(UTMZone, other.UTMZone) && double.Equals(hemisphere, other.hemisphere);
    }
}
```

**Edit** Using Daniel A. Whites advice I've used a different double comparision method. Unfortunately its still not identifying the key:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    //return base.Equals (obj);
    UTMCoordinate other = obj as UTMCoordinate;
    if (other == null)
        return false;

    //return double.Equals(x, other.x) && double.Equals(y, other.y) && double.Equals(elev, other.elev) && uint.Equals(UTMZone, other.UTMZone) && double.Equals(hemisphere, other.hemisphere);
    return Math.Abs (x-other.x) <= DIF_TOLERANCE && Math.Abs (y-other.y) <= DIF_TOLERANCE && Math.Abs (elev-other.elev) <= DIF_TOLERANCE && uint.Equals(UTMZone, other.UTMZone) && hemisphere == other.hemisphere;
}
```

Comment: fyi doubles don't have fixed precision. That might give you a clue.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on both methods. Do they get called when you expect? Do they return the values you expect?

Comment: I just tried. `planes.ContainsKey(nCoord)` returened `true` for me.

Comment: Try implementing `IEquatable<T>`

Comment: @DanielA.White: The conditions under which doubles may be used at higher precision and thereby have unexpected inequalities should not include comparing fields to each other.

Comment: Please post an executable repro.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks for the advice. I've used a different method to compare the doubles (see edit) but it still doesn't identify it?

Comment: Your code executes just fine (even without the tolerance) - `exists` is true.

Comment: This is probably not an issue, but you do know that the value produced by `GetHashCode` must be immutable? So if you base it on the values of your object's properties then those properties must also be immutable.

Comment: Your code, as posted here, works fine for me. So my above comment may be the issue. In your "real" code do you vary any of the property values before checking the dictionary?

Comment: @JakeM:Code you Posted Works good without Equals method in my machine.It returns true when i add ncord and false when i remove..Have you made any other changes apart from the code you posted ?

Comment: Are you following **all** of the guidelines and rules for GetHashcode? http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I take your code from your question:

```
Dictionary<UTMCoordinate, int> planes = new Dictionary<UTMCoordinate, int>();
UTMCoordinate nCoord    = new UTMCoordinate(337394.136407966, 6263820.40182064, 0, 56, UTMCoordinate.Hemisphere.H_SOUTHERN);
planes[nCoord]          = 1;

bool exists = planes.ContainsKey(nCoord);
```

The value I get for `exists` is `true`.

However, if I do this:

```
nCoord.x = 1.0;
exists = planes.ContainsKey(nCoord);
```

The value for `exists` suddenly becomes `false` even though the object is still in the dictionary. This is because the value for `GetHashCode` has changed. It was `-1473667404`, but after the assignment of the property `x` it becomes `201352392`.

The dictionary uses the value of `GetHashCode` to determine which bucket to put the key in so when the hash code changes the dictionary may try finding the key in the wrong bucket and then reports that it doesn't contain the key.

I suspect in your code that is what is happening.

So you need to change your object so that it is immutable.

```
public double               x               { get; private set; }
public double               y               { get; private set; }
public double               elev            { get; private set; }
public uint                 UTMZone         { get; private set; }
public Hemisphere           hemisphere      { get; private set; }
```

And then do NOT change any of the values outside of the constructor.